Struggling to understand a proof of the Well-Ordering Principle in Jech's Set Theory
I'm struggling to understand a proof of the Well-Ordering Principle in Jech's Set Theory:

Proof. Let $A$ be a set. To well-order $A$, it suffices to construct a transfinite one-to-one sequence $\langle a_\alpha : \alpha < \theta \rangle$ that enumerates $A$. That we can do by induction, using a choice function $f$ for the family $S$ of all nonempty subsets of $A$. We let for every $\alpha$
$$
a_\alpha = f(A - \{a_\xi : \xi < \alpha\})
$$
if $A - \{a_\xi : \xi < \alpha\}$ is nonempty. Let $\theta$ be the least ordinal such that
$$
A = \{a_\xi : \xi < \theta\}.
$$
Clearly, $\langle a_\alpha : \alpha < \theta \rangle$ enumerates $A$.

I do not understand exactly how the $a_\alpha$ are defined. Is transfinite induction being used to define them?

How would you well-order the [positive] rationals? You start with, say, $0$, then you choose the next element, maybe it was $1$, then another one, maybe $\frac12$, then another one, maybe $\frac13$, then another one, maybe $\frac23$, etc.
We can also specify a concrete rule. For example: start at $0$, then at each step pick the least positive rational whose reduced form is $\frac pq$, and if no such choice is possible, pick the least $q$ possible that hasn't been used and continue. If this is not possible, we have exhausted the positive rationals. Do mind, we are not trying to well-order the rationals in the same order as the natural numbers, just a well-order.
Then if we want to compare, say $\frac13$ and $\frac52$ we first ask about the denominator, and $\frac52$ has a lower denominator than $\frac13$, which is why it will appear first.
The same goes in this proof. You just keep on choosing the next point, and to do this we need transfinite induction, but to use transfinite induction we need to have a fixed function that allows us to make the choices for how to proceed given some initial segment. So, a choice function does exactly that. It allows us to say, as long as we did not define a surjection onto $A$, there is still elements to use, choose one, and keep going.
